# How to get forienkeys data in laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, model, foreign-key-relationship

I am implementing chat in my application using laravel. I have these Models:

```
`Users: id, name `
`Pages: id, user_id(foreign_key from Users table (id)), name`
`Posts: id, page_id(foreign_key from Pages table (id)), user_id(foreign_key from Users table (id)), body`
`Comments: id, post_id(foreign_key from Posts table (id)), user_id(foreign_key from Users table (id)), body`
```

I need to query followings

> Get all posts of user with comments and with user
>
> Get all posts of a page with comments and with user

I am using below query to get all posts of a page, but how can I include its comments and user details;

`Page::with('post')->findOrFail($pageId)->post;`

**EDIT**

---

```
USER Model: User.php
```

---

```
public function page() {
  return $this->hasMany('Page');
}

public function post() {
  return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

---

```
Page Model: Page.php
```

---

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function post() {
  return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

---

```
Post Model: Post.php
```

---

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function page() {
  return $this->belongsTo('Page');
}

public function comments() {
  return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

---

```
Comment Model: Comment.php
```

---

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function post() {
  return $this->belongsTo('Post');
}
```

Comment: Please show the models so that we can see what relations you have defined

Comment: I have edited my question to include models

Answer (score 0):

As your relationships are not that clear to me, i can only provide some hints where to look.

- Getting posts of a user with comments sounds like laravel query scopes: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes
- You may also query for relationship existence: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations
- And Lazy Eager Loading could also help to retrieve the necessary instances.